# How to scale a set of points so that a given vector's magnitude becomes 1?

Tags: linear-algebra

For example, I have a set of 5 xy points named **p1** to **p5**. I need to scale the entire point set so that the **p4p1** vector's magnitude becomes equal 1. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  An [introduction to posting mathematical expressions](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) might help you convey your meaning to Readers more clearly.  For example, if there are five points, what defines "the **p4p1** vector"?  Is it the direction from one point to another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compute the length $L$ of $p_4 - p_1$; using $p_4 = (x_4, y_4)$ and similar naming for other $xy$-pairs, 
$$
L = \sqrt{(x_4 - x_1)^2 + (y_4 - y_1)^2}.
$$

Then you want to scale your points by $\frac{1}{L}$, i.e. set
$$
x_i' = \frac{1}{L}x_i\\y_i' = \frac{1}{L}y_i
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will accept your answer as the correct one since it is a bit more detailed, but I appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Find the length of the vector from $p_4$ to $p_1$ and call it $L$. Now simply divide all of your points with this factor.